# Vim - Set number command on startup

Tags: vim, vimrc

What is the file to edit, to show lines number on startup using vim ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be [`.vimrc`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file) located in your home folder. Do:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

Add:

```
set number
```